# Angular 4 Routing - base-href gets prepended to hashPath

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular4-router

When the built version of the angular app is placed in the root, it generates the url just fine

http://thisismydomain.com/#/master/data-source-management/data-sources/list

But when it is placed somewhere deeper inside the root, and I use base-href, the router still behaves fine while loading the page, but once it is loaded, the base-href gets prepended to the hashpath like the following:

http://thisismydomain.com/deeper/inside/#/deeper/inside/master/data-source-management/data-sources/list

Expected Url:

http://thisismydomain.com/deeper/inside/#/master/data-source-management/data-sources/list

I found out the problem was associated with the injection of APP_BASE_HREF entry in the import section of app.module.ts?

```
providers: [
AuthenticationService,
KaribaService,
GlobalService,
NotificationService,
/*
{
  provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
  useFactory: getBaseHref,
  deps: [PlatformLocation]
},
*/
CustomizationService
```

]

Commenting that out solves the problem, but I need it in order to inject BASE_HREF in my services to pull contents from assets folder.
HELP?

P.S. I am using lazy loading.

Comment: Can you post the rest of app.routing?  Mainly the parts with the routes.

Comment: @Cruril Thanks but I was able to resolve it with a workaround. I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by creating a CustomLocationStrategy by extending the HashLocationStrategy, since this seemed to be the only solution.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HashLocationStrategy} from "@angular/common";

@Injectable()    
export class CustomLocationStrategy extends HashLocationStrategy {

  prepareExternalUrl(internal: string): string {
    const url = this.getBaseHref() + '#' + internal;
    return url;
  }
}
```

Imported the custom class along with APP_BASE_HREF and LocationStrategy in app.module.ts

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy } from "@angular/common";
import { CustomLocationStrategy } from './common/services/customLocationStrategy.service';
```

and added the following in the providers section.

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF, 
    useValue: window.location.pathname
  }, 
  {
    provide: LocationStrategy, 
    useClass: CustomLocationStrategy
  }
]
```